# Why use Collection.empty[T] instead of new Collection[T]()

Tags: scala

I was wondering if there is a good reason to use `Collection.empty[T]` instead of `new Collection[T]()` (or the inverse) ? Or is it just a personal preference ?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [List.empty vs. List() vs. new List()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686213/list-empty-vs-list-vs-new-list)

Comment: I don't think it is an exact duplicate, because the other question specifically focus on `List`, and as a result so do the answers. This question is more about a general rule for any collection. For `List` an easy answer is that it is abstract and that you can't even do `new List[T]()`. That is not the case of every collection, and thus a broader answer is required here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling `new Collection[T]()` will create a new instance every time. On the other hand, `Collection.empty[T]` will most likely always return the same singleton `object`, usually defined somewhere as

```
object Empty extends Collection[Nothing] ...
```

which will be much faster. **Edit:** This is only possible for immutable collections, mutable collections have to return a new instance every time `empty` is called.

Comment: I had this idea, too, but I checked a few actual classes from the Scala Standard Library (conveniently linked from the central ScalaDoc HTML pages!) and found this not to be the case. There are some classes (notably the `Sorted` variants) have implicit constructor parameters that make different empty instances non-shareable.

Comment: @RandallSchulz Did you check mutable or immutable collections? For mutable collections it's of course not possible to have such a singleton object. For example, mutable `Set` has `override def empty[A]: Set[A] = HashSet.empty[A]`. But immutable structures can use singletons, like immutable `Set` does: `override def empty[A]: Set[A] = EmptySet.asInstanceOf[Set[A]]`. So mutable collections don't really need `empty` but they have it so that they comply to the uniform API, like both `Set` objects implement `SetFactory`.

Comment: Actually, I just went to the member cross-reference forj `empty` and just checked a few out. I didn't pay attention to which part of the hierarchy (`mutable` vs. `immutable`) they were in. But still, any class with more constructor parameters than the members will not be able to share `empty` instances.

Answer (score 1):

You should always prefer `Collection.empty[Type]`.

Comment: Could you explain why do you think so?

Comment: I believe it's a clearer expression of your intent. Additionally, it does not require the instantiation of an (empty) repeated-params argument list.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `Collection.empty[T]` being  clearer on the intent, you should favour it for the same reason that you should favour factory methods in general when instantiating a collection: because thoses factories abstract away some implementation details that you might not (or should not) care about.
By example, when  you do `Seq.empty[String]` you actually get an instance of `List[String]`. You could directly instantiate a `List[String]` but if all you care about is to have **some** `Seq` you would introduce a needless dependency to `List` (well OK, actually you cannot as it stands, because `List` is already abstract, but let's pretend we can for the sake of the argument)
The whole point of factories is precisely to have some amount of separation of concern and not bother with unnecessary instantiation details.

As another more elaborate example, let's talk about `collection.immutable.HashMap`. This one is very much a **concrete** class so you might think there is no need for a factory here. Except that for optimization purpose the factory in the companion object `collection.immutable.HashMap` will actually create different sub-classes depending on the number of elements that you initialize the map with (see this question: [Scala: how to make a Hash(Trie)Map from a Map (via Anorm in Play)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14687042/scala-how-to-make-a-hashtriemap-from-a-map-via-anorm-in-play/14688161#14688161)). Obviously, if you directly instantiate `collection.immutable.HashMap` you will lose this optimization.

Another common optimization for `empty` is to always return (when it is an immutable collection) the same instance, yet another useful optimization that you would lose by directly instantiating the collection.

So as a rule of thumb, as far as you can you should use the factories that are provided by the various collection companion objects, so as to shield yourself from unneeded dependencies while at the same time benefiting from potential optimizations provided by the collection framework.

`empty` is just a special case of factory, and so the same logic applies.