# how to declare a mutable map with key value typing in Scala without initialization

Tags: scala

I tried to declare an empty Map, but modifying it leads to a mismatch error and was wondering how I can resolve this:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Map

val m = Map()
m(3) = 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala collections provide `empty` method for such situations

```
val m = Map.empty[Int, Int]
m(3) = 2
```

or

```
Map[Int, Int]()
```

which is equivalent to

```
Map.apply[Int, Int]()
```

When calling just `Map()` Scala infers `Nothing` for both key and value

```
mutable.Map()
// val res0: mutable.Map[Nothing,Nothing] = HashMap()
```

An [advantage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14815359/5205022) of `empty` approach is that in case of immutable collections it might be more performant, however this will not be the case for mutable map.

Comment: You can also use type ascription or explicit type signature in the variable. In any case, it is worth mentioning that in general, the `empty` method is the preferred solution.